# where to place @Transactional annotation when service layer contains call to external resources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, transactions

here is the situation
have a method in service layer that calls another third-party service, meanwhile it does
query using JPA repository, and it cause org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException:

```
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at ....
```

how do you think I can handle this rather than using a circuit breaker on a third party calling part?
for whatever reason that method may took some time to execute, but I don't want to keep the connection to the databse. is there any way I can handle this?

Comment: WIthout knowing if that call is mandatory for the commit or the data at hand this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be *easiest* if you just kept the DB connection open while performing REST call. If it's a simple `SELECT`, then it doesn't consume much resources:

```
@Transactional
public void m1() {
    SomeClass o = repository.findSomething(...);
    externalService.call(o);
}
```

But if you don't want to keep the connection open (which is *better*), then simply redesign it like this:

```
public void m1() {
    SomeClass o = otherService.transactionalMethod();
    externalService.call(o);
}
```

So your `m1()` method isn't `@Transactional` anymore, while the TX is now started and finished in the first line. Alternatively, you can do programmatic tx management and not bother moving the tx-related logic into a separate service.

PS: while not a good practice, you can also mark your Repository methods `@Transactional` - so you won't have to delegate the TX call to another service. Spring Data for example does just that. Depending on the expectations on the quality of the code this may be acceptable.